# How to combine two different length lists in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to combine two different length lists. For example;

```
val list1 = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val list2 = listOf("a","b","c")
```

I want to result like this

```
(1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,5)
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Join both list as objetc and then use a comparator https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparator/index.html

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use the `.zip` function for that

```
list1.zip(list2){ a,b -> listOf(a,b)}.flatten()
```

The only problem is that it will only process elements, with both sets, so if (like in the example) let's have different size - it will not work

The alternative could be to add specific markers and filter them or to just use iterators for that. I found an elegant solution with `sequence{..}` function

```
 val result = sequence {
    val first = list1.iterator()
    val second = list2.iterator()
    while (first.hasNext() && second.hasNext()) {
      yield(first.next())
      yield(second.next())
    }

    yieldAll(first)
    yieldAll(second)
  }.toList()
```

Comment: My lists has different size so it doesn't work for my situation

Answer (score 6):

1. If the elements from the source lists can occur in any order in the resulting list, then

```
>>> list1 + list2
res12: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Any> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a, b, c]
```

2. If the elements from the source lists should alternate in the resulting list and list1 is longer than list2, then

```
>>> list1.zip(list2).flatMap { listOf(it.first, it.second) } + list1.drop(list2.size)
res16: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Any> = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, 5]
```

Comment: nice one, but it requires you to know which will be the bigger list,  in order to append the correct list (from which you dropped)

Comment: True and a generic solution can be created by changing the second addend to `if (list1.size > list2.size) list1.drop(list2.size) else list2.drop(list1.size)`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this:

```
val mergedList = with(setOf(list1, list2).sortedByDescending { it.count() }) {
    first().mapIndexed { index, e ->
        listOfNotNull(e, last().getOrNull(index))
    }
}.flatten()
```

First, you put both lists in a `Set`, then you sort it (descending) by the number of elements yielding a list of lists.

The first list has the most elements will be used for iteration.

Using `mapIndexed` you can use the `index` to access the corresponding element in the second list. If there is none, `null` is returned and it will be filtered out by `listOfNotNull`. In the end you flatten the resulting list of lists and you get the desired result:

> [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, 5]

Answer (score 2):

I think Eugenes answer already contains all you need to know to combine two lists (be it `zip` or combining all elements).

In case you want to combine an arbitrary number of lists, one item per alternating list, you may also be interested in the following approach:

```
fun combine(vararg lists: List<*>) : List<Any> = mutableListOf<Any>().also {
  combine(it, lists.map(List<*>::iterator))
}

private tailrec fun combine(targetList: MutableList<Any>, iterators: List<Iterator<*>>) {
  iterators.asSequence()
          .filter(Iterator<*>::hasNext)
          .mapNotNull(Iterator<*>::next)
          .forEach { targetList += it }
  if (iterators.asSequence().any(Iterator<*>::hasNext))
    combine(targetList, iterators)
}
```

Calling it then looks as follows and leads to the value seen in the comment:

```
combine(list1, list2) // List containing: 1, "a", 2, "b", 3, "c", 4, 5
combine(list1, list2, listOf("hello", "world")) // 1, "a", "hello", 2, "b", "world", 3, "c", 4, 5
```

A simplified approach to the second part of Eugenes answer could be implemented using following code; that, of course, isn't lazy anymore as you get a list back ;-) (but maybe you even translated it directly to a list, so you can also use this approach):

```
fun List<Any>.combine(other: List<Any>) : List<Any> = mutableListOf<Any>().also {
  val first = iterator()
  val second = other.iterator()
  while (first.hasNext() || second.hasNext()) {
    if (first.hasNext()) it.add(first.next())
    if (second.hasNext()) it.add(second.next())
  }
}
```

Calling it would work as follows:

```
list1.combine(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
fun <T> zip(vararg iterables: Iterable<T>): List<T> = iterables
.map { it.iterator() }
.toList()
.let { iterators ->
    mutableListOf<T>()
        .also { list ->
            while (
              iterators.any {if (it.hasNext()) list.add(it.next()) else false }
            ) { }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Your lists are of inconvertible types (Ints and Strings) so you have to have `MutableList<Any>` so that you can add both types:

```
val allItems = mutableListOf<Any>(1,2,3,4,5)
val list2 = listOf("a","b","c")
allItems.addAll(list2)
```

Comment: I can use mutableList. it ok, but addAll result is 1,2,3,4,5,6,"a","b","c" right? I want that result is 1,"a",2,"b",3,"c",4,5

Comment: You're not specifying the sort order. Do you want the items to alternate or just be sorted?